# WCF Client- Removing whitespace from Content-Type header

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, client, webservice-client

I am trying to query a SOAP web service which requires that the Content-Type header does not have any whitespace. I'm using a WCF client for the purpose, and was able to remove the whitespace between `application/soap+xml;` and `charset="UTF-8"` by creating a custom [MessageEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx) -

`Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset="UTF-8"; action="RealTimeTransaction"`

But I can't seem to figure out a way to remove the whitespace before `action="RealTimeTransaction"` in the Content-Type that gets sent to the server. Any ideas please?